# iPhone: Inherit a protocol or category from another protocol or category

Tags: iphone

I want to inherit a protocol from another protocol, same like that i want to inherit a category from another category. I would be able to resolve some complex tasks if i can implement these two ways.

Could someone please advise, whether is it first possible or not? If yes, what would be the syntax to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It has already been asked and answered, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470994/can-objective-c-protocols-and-categories-be-inherited

Comment: ok thank you. I got answer from this like, Categories can not be inherited from another category where as Protocol can.

Comment: exactly! You'll also see the syntax for protocol inheritance.

Comment: yes, i saw protocols can inherit just like class inheritance.thanks very much.